How challenging is it to transition from industry to a postdoc position after a PhD?
I completed my PhD 2.5 years ago, and since then, I've been working in industry, specifically in data analytics and applied research roles related to the agricultural and industrial sectors. I now find myself more interested in research and am considering a transition back into academia, specifically into a postdoctoral position, ideally in my research areas.
I’m wondering:
How difficult is it to move from industry to a postdoc?
Are professors typically open to hiring candidates with industry experience, or do they tend to prefer fresh PhDs?
I’d appreciate any insights or advice on how to make this transition smoother. Thank you!

Every case is different. It depends on what you have to offer and on the needs of the institution.

At least in my field, I've never heard of somebody going from industry to a postdoc. But it's not because they can't do it, it's because nobody even tries to do it, because it would entail an 80% pay cut.

Any publications you did or have in the pipeline will be invaluable, as will any academic contacts you have. Reach out to the latter and have a discussion with them. They will likely not have open positions, but they may know someone who knows someone who knows someone..., and they will be much better placed to give you advice tailored to your field and your local academic culture than random strangers on the internet.
